# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, where 'str' is from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, list, io, int

the code below has provided me with the error...

```
particle_array = np.empty((1,N))
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I have looked at several other questions that provide the same error and the answers suggest that the term I use for my range is not an integer, however I am still unsure why this is the case.

```
def particles_array(N):
        # where n is the number of particles

        particle_array = np.empty((1,N))

        for i in len(N):

            particle = Particle3D.__init__(self,label,mass,pos,vel)

            np.append(particle_array, particle)


        return particle_array
```

(this code is used to obtain my value for 'N' from a text file)

```
text_file = open(param)

data_list = []

for line in text_file:

    data_list.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])

N = data_list[0]
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you want `data_list.extend([float(x) for x in line.split()])` or else you append a list to a list, and `data_list[0]` will be a ... (drumroll) ... list

Comment: thank you very much, ill give that a go and see how i get on! :-)